# Why can't I add custom key/value pair to orm_filters in TastyPie Advanced filter definition?

Tags: django, tastypie

In following the example provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10022244/1386588 I am running into an issue with the sample code provided.

I have the following advanced filter definition in place:

```
def build_filters(self, filters=None):
        if filters is None:
            filters = {}

        orm_filters = super(TaggedResource, self).build_filters(filters)

        if('query' in filters):
            query = filters['query']
            print query
            qset = (
                    Q(comment__icontains=query) |
                    Q(media_text__icontains=query)
                    )
            orm_filters.extend({'custom': qset})
```

And the problem I am running into is the fact that orm_filters is a dict mapping and not a list.  Therefore, I am getting the error:

```
"error_message": "'dict' object has no attribute 'extend'"
```

If I try to add the key and value pair as I would with a regular dict object:

```
orm_filters['custom'] = qset
```

I am getting the following error when I try to `return orm_filters` after adding the 'custom' key:

```
"error_message": "Cannot resolve keyword 'custom' into field. Choices are: comment, id, media_text, ..."
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

I have been trying to find a solution for this for a while now without any luck, thanks in advance for your help here!

**UPDATE: I think the issue is that my attempt to override apply_filters is not instantiating:**

```
def apply_filters(self, request, applicable_filters):
        print 'applied filters'
        if 'custom' in applicable_filters:
            custom = applicable_filters.pop('custom')
        else:
            custom = None

        semi_filtered = super(TaggedResource, self).apply_filters(request, applicable_filters)

        return semi_filtered.filter(custom) if custom else semi_filtered
```

This is likely why I am getting the cannot resolve keyword 'custom' error, because I am expecting the apply_filters method here to remove 'custom' after grabbing it from applicable_filters.

Not sure what is wrong in my apply_filters def.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing:

```
orm_filters.extend({'custom': qset})
```

to:

```
orm_filters.update(**qset)
```

**update:** (tested code)

```
def build_filters(self, filters=None):
    filters = filters

    applicable_filters = super(TaggedResource, self).build_filters(filters)

    query = filters.get('query')
    if query:
        qset = (
            Q(comment__icontains=query) |
            Q(media_text__icontains=query)
        )
        applicable_filters['custom'] = qset

    return applicable_filters

def apply_filters(self, request, applicable_filters):
    custom = None
    if 'custom' in applicable_filters:
        custom = applicable_filters.pop('custom')

    semi_filtered = super(TaggedResource, self).apply_filters(request, applicable_filters)

    return semi_filtered.filter(**custom) if custom else semi_filtered
```

Comment: I tried what you put, but I need to have a key as well ('custom').  `orm_filters.update(**{'custom':qset})` works to add 'custom' to the dict with a Q object as it's value pair, but it is still giving me the same error as before when I try to return it:  `"error_message": "Cannot resolve keyword 'custom' into field. Choices are: comment, ..."`

Comment: Offcourse you get that message, custom isn't a field, you can't filter on something that doesn't exists, why are you doing that?

Comment: I thought it would be okay since I am only adding it to the mapping within `build_filters`.  The filter is not actually running with 'custom' - [As is shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10022244/1386588), I am popping 'custom' off after it has been passed to applicable filters.  `custom = applicable_filters.pop('custom')`

Comment: CHANGE return semi_filtered.filter(custom) if custom else semi_filtered TO return semi_filtered.filter(**custom) if custom else semi_filtered

Comment: I understand what you are recommending; however, I don't think it addresses the real issue which is the fact that the apply_filters method is not being called at all during the request.  This is likely why I am getting the error `Cannot resolve keyword 'custom' into field.`

Comment: Your apply_filters is called just fine, the problem is it expects callback kwargs: self.get_object_list(request).filter(**applicable_filters)

Comment: Your code above worked great!  Thanks so much for your persistent help.