# Tastypie: Advance filter with complex query

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, tastypie

```
model.py
class Device(models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    major = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    minor = models.CharField(max_length=10)

resource.py
class DeviceResourceV3(ModelResource):
    '''Fetch device details'''
    class Meta:
        queryset = Device.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'device'
        always_return_data = True
        filtering = {
            'uuid': ['exact', 'in'],
            'id': ['exact']
    }
```

Requested API Call :

```
/api/device?uuidmm__in=XXXXXX,YYYYY
```

Now as per the requirement we have to create a filter which will result all the devices for whom (uuid + major + minor) in [XXXXXX,YYYYY]

I have gone though the advance filters mentioned in 
http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html and 
[Django Tastypie Advanced Filtering: How to do complex lookups with Q objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021749/django-tastypie-advanced-filtering-how-to-do-complex-lookups-with-q-objects)
 but this perticular use case is getting too complex. Can anyone suggest the appropriate build_filters and apply_filters method for this query, or any other simple approach for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to make use of annotations:

```
class DeviceResourceV3(ModelResource):
    uuidmm = fields.CharField(max_length=120)


    class Meta:
        queryset = Device.objects.all().annotate(uuidmm=(Concat('uuid', 'major', 'minor'))),
        resource_name = 'device'
        always_return_data = True
        filtering = {
            'uuid': ['exact', 'in'],
            'id': ['exact'],
            'uuidmm': ['exact', 'in']
    }
```

I can't test it right now if the "__in" would work with this approach. If not, you could also overwrite the `apply_filters`:

```
def apply_filters(self, request, applicable_filters):
    semi_filtered = super(DeviceResourceV3, self).apply_filters(request, applicable_filters)

    uuidmms = request.GET.get('uuidmm__in', None)

    if uuidmms:
        # handle your filtering here, e.g. by combining all uuidmms to one string and check, and exclude the ones that are not in the combined string
```