# Django Tastypie filter OR statement

Tags: django, tastypie

Suppose I'm filtering products in the Django Tastypie API and I want to return all products with `product_type = 'cracker' OR product_name = 'oreo'`. Using this syntax:

```
localhost:8000/api?product_type=cracker&product_name__icontains=oreo
```

This will return products which are crackers AND are named oreo. How can I turn that into an OR statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. According to the Django query documentation here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

complex queries (such as OR statements) can only be done with the Q() object. Tastypie doesn't have special syntax to handle complex queries in URLs, but you can build custom queries in resources, as in this answer:

[Django Tastypie Advanced Filtering: How to do complex lookups with Q objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021749/django-tastypie-advanced-filtering-how-to-do-complex-lookups-with-q-objects)